# Cannot read records in each columns and rows from excel file using php

Tags: php, excel

I have a form where user upload a excel file when click on upload submit button then file is move into folder but its cannot read records of each rows and columns in excel files. Here is form code

```
<form id="TypeValidation" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="donor_attachment" id="donor_attachment" />
        <button type="submit" name="donor_file" id="donor_file" value="donor_file" class="btn btn-success btn-round fileinput-exists">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

file is submit through ajax

```
$("#TypeValidation").on('submit',(function(e) 
 { 
  var fileUploadID = $(this).find('button[name="donor_file"]').val();
  e.preventDefault();   
   $.ajax({
        url: "fn_dsr_wizard_submit.php?submitid="+fileUploadID,
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: "html",    
        success: function (result) { 
        alert(result);
        location.reload();
        if(result=='1'){
            location.replace("donors_dashboard.php");
        }else {
            location.replace("donors_dashboard.php");               
        }
        }
    }); 

    }

    ));
```

here is fn_dsr_wizard_sunbmit.php code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submitid']) && $_REQUEST['submitid']=='donor_file'){
global $con;

$userid = $_SESSION['Cont_ID'];
$company_id = $_SESSION['Company_ID'];

//Donor File Attachment
$F_filePath="../../uploads/ds_information/donor/";
$_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'];
if ($_FILES['donor_attachment']['name']!=""){
$donor_attachment = date('dmyhis')."_".$userid."_".$company_id."_".$_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['donor_attachment']['tmp_name'], $F_filePath.$donor_attachment);

$fileextension = explode(".",$donor_attachment);
if($fileextension[1]=="xls") {

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$html="<table border='1'>";
 for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
  { 
    if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
     {
    for($j=1;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
    { 
        $html.="<tr>";
        for($k=1;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells][$j]);$k++) // This loop is created to get data in a table format.
        {
            $html.="<td>";
            $html.=$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][$k];
            $html.="</td>";
        }
        $eid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1]);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][2]);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][3]);
        $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][4]);
        //$query = "insert into excel(eid,name,email,dob) values('".$eid."','".$name."','".$email."','".$dob."')";

        //mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $html.="</tr>";
    }
}

}

 $html.="</table>";
 echo $eid;
 echo $name;
 echo $email;
 echo $dob;
} 
}
else {$donor_attachment=$_SESSION['donor_attachment']; unset($_SESSION['donor_attachment']);}

if($_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'] !=''){
    $_SESSION['fileInsert']="donor_file_success_msg";
    echo 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['filenotInsert']="donor_file_error_msg";
    echo 0;
}

 //}
}
```

Issue is that recods are not read from each columns and rows in excel and when add this line `$excel->read('$donor_attachment');` after this line `$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();` then show me alert error of file is not readable. I want that records are read from excel file

Comment: are you able to open the file manually in Excel?  Maybe the problem is with the file itself, not with the upload or read processes.

Comment: yes i am able to open a excel file manually and its problem with read process

Comment: are you sure this path is pointing to the right spot? `"../../uploads/ds_information/donor/"`... another troubleshooting step is to replace that with the absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: yes I am fixing this error and I am add this line $filepath = "../../uploads/ds_information/donor/".$donor_attachment; before this line if($fileextension[1]=="xls")

Comment: why are you not passing the file path to `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader()`? or am I missing something here?

Comment: I am editing my question its working now

Comment: `public function __construct($file = '', $store_extended_info = true, $outputEncoding = '')` the default `$file` path is an empty string, not providing it will surely throw an unreadable exception/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I modified my code then read a records from excel file

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submitid']) && $_REQUEST['submitid']=='donor_file'){
global $con;

$userid = $_SESSION['Cont_ID'];
$company_id = $_SESSION['Company_ID'];

//Donor File Attachment
$F_filePath="../../uploads/ds_information/donor/";
$_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'];
if ($_FILES['donor_attachment']['name']!=""){
$donor_attachment = date('dmyhis')."_".$userid."_".$company_id."_".$_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['donor_attachment']['tmp_name'], $F_filePath.$donor_attachment);

$filepath = "../../uploads/ds_information/donor/".$donor_attachment;
$fileextension = explode(".",$donor_attachment);
if($fileextension[1]=="xls") {

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->read($filepath);  
$html="<table border='1'>";
 for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
  { 
    if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
  {
    for($j=3;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
    { 
        $html.="<tr>";
        for($k=3;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells][$j]);$k++) // This loop is created to get data in a table format.
        {
            $html.="<td>";
            $html.=$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][$k];
            $html.="</td>";
        }
        $eid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1]);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][2]);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][3]);
        $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][4]);
        //$query = "insert into excel(eid,name,email,dob) values('".$eid."','".$name."','".$email."','".$dob."')";

        //mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $html.="</tr>";
    }
  }
 }

$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
 } 
}
 else {$donor_attachment=$_SESSION['donor_attachment']; unset($_SESSION['donor_attachment']);}

if($_FILES['donor_attachment']['name'] !=''){
    $_SESSION['fileInsert']="donor_file_success_msg";
    echo 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['filenotInsert']="donor_file_error_msg";
    echo 0;
}   
//}
}
```